# JPA2: Nested Primary Key class cannot persist as binding null

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I'm using `JPA 2.x` with `EclipseLink 2.5.1` with `nested primary key class` as the following: -

#### Note: The behind the scene environment

```
1. OS: Windows 7 64 Bits
2. JDK: 1.7.0_65 64 Bits
3. Maven: 3.2.2
4. Arquillian: 1.1.5.Final
5. Container: Glassfish 4 embedded
6. Database: Derby 10.10.2.0 embedded
```

#### The Master PK

```java
@Embeddable
public class MasterPk {
    @Column(
        name   = "MASTER_ID",
        length = 5
    )
    private String masterId;

    //----> Setter/Getter is omitted
}
```

#### The Master

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MASTER_TAB")
public class Master {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MaskerPk id;

    @Column(
        name   = "MASTER_NAME",
        length = 40
    )
    private String masterName;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "master"
    )
    private List<Detail> details;

    //----> Setter/Getter is omitted
}
```

#### The Detail PK

```java
@Embeddable
public class DetailPk {

    //----> THE NESTED IS HERE.
    @Embedded
    private MasterPk masterId;

    @Column(
        name   = "DETAIL_ID",
        length = 5
    )
    private String detailId;

    //----> Setter/Getter is omitted
}
```

#### The Detail

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "DETAIL_TAB")
public class Detail {

    @EmbeddedId
    private DetailPk id;

    @Column(
        name   = "DETAIL_NAME",
        length = 40
    )
    private String detailName;

    @MapsId("masterId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(
            name                 = "MASTER_ID",
            referencedColumnName = "MASTER_ID",
            nullable             = false
        )
    })
    private Master master;

    //----> Setter/Getter is omitted
}
```

#### The coding for persisting the Detail

```java
MasterPk masterPk = new MasterPk();
masterPk.setId("001"); //there is a 001 existed in the db

DetailPk detailPk = new DetailPk();
detailPk.setMasterId(masterPk);
detailPk.setDetailId("001"); //new detail to persist

Detail detail = new Detail();
detail.id(detailPk);
detail.setDetailName("detail-name");

em.persist(detail);
```

#### The persistence XML

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
                   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="unittest" transaction-type="JTA">

        <jta-data-source>jdbc/unittest</jta-data-source>

        <class>com.test.MasterPk</class>
        <class>com.test.Master</class>
        <class>com.test.DetiailPk</class>
        <class>com.test.Detail</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" 
                      value="create-tables" />                     
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                      value="both"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.application-location" 
                      value="target"/>                     
            <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" 
                      value="createDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" 
                      value="dropDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When the project starts, all tables are created correctly, especially the `primary key` and `foreign key`. But when `persist` with the coding., there are some trouble about the `Detail` as the `Detail.masterId.id` is null. The `EclipseLink` shows me as

```
Column 'MASTER_ID' cannot accept a NULL value.

INSERT INTO DETAIL_TAB (DETAILE_NAME, DETAIL_ID, MASTER_ID)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [detail-name, 001, null]

//
//----> We may be noticed that the masterId is not null. It is printed as 001.
//
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Detail(detailName=detail-name,
                                id=DetailPk(detailId=001,
                                            masterId=(MasterPk(masterId=001))
                                            )
                                )
                         )
```

I double check by printing all `field` in this `object-graph` and can confirm that the `masterId` is not null as well. I'm not sure if doing something wrong/misunderstanding. Could you please help to advise how to solve this issue?

#### Edit 1

1. Fix the `@ManyToOne` at the `Detail.java`. It is a typo when copying and pasting to this question
2. Try to add the `@Embedded` to the `masterId` at the class `DetailPk`.

   Edit 1 result still faces the same issue.

#### Edit 2

1. Add the coding for create the `detail` and `persist`
2. I create the `MasterPk` directly without finding the `Master`.

   Further question, Should I need to find the `Mater` entity for getting its `id` and assigning it to the `DetailPk` instead of create it directly via `new MasterPk();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `MasterPK` is an embeddable it should be annotated with `@Embedded`:

```
@Embeddable
public class DetailPk {

    @Embedded
    private MasterPk masterId;
    ...
}
```

I guess `Detail` entity is also missing `@ManyToOne` (or it's just intentional?)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DETAIL_TAB")
public class Detail {
    ...
    @MapsId("masterId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(
            name                 = "MASTER_ID",
            referencedColumnName = "MASTER_ID",
            nullable             = false
        )
    })
    private Master master;
}
```

---

Ad **Edit 2**

The following statement

```sql
INSERT INTO DETAIL_TAB (DETAILE_NAME, DETAIL_ID, MASTER_ID)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [detail-name, 001, null]
```

means that the *owning side* of the master-detail relationship (represented by `@ManyToOne` association) is null. 
From JPA point of view this looks as follows:

- `MASTER_ID` column is related to `master` field in `Detail` entity
- `Master` entity uses `MasterPK` as the primary key
- `Detail` entity references `Master` with `master` field
- because `Detail` entity acts as the owner of the relationship it would be good to specify cascading on it, i.e.  `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`

Based on the above, to make thing work we would need to set up the *owning side*, for example:

```java
Master master = new Master();
master.id(masterPk);    

Detail detail = new Detail();
detail.id(detailPk);
detail.setMaster(master); // the owning side of the master-detail relationship

master.setDetail(detail); // mandatory if CascadeType.PERSIST is not defined
em.persist(detail);
```

This will result in:

```sql
INSERT INTO DETAIL_TAB (DETAIL_NAME, DETAIL_ID, MASTER_ID)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [detail-name, 001, 001]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The `@ManyToOne` is a typo when copying and pasting to the question. I've edited the question about the `@Embedded`.

Comment: I would like to ask further. If I should find the `master` for getting its `id` before assigning it to the `detailPK`?

Comment: Yes, the master-detail relationship is not assigned. I have updated my answer.

Comment: After adding the relationship as your mention, It works. Thank you so much.